# Optimisation problem : How to solve a Knapsack problem with boolean variables, a user basket usecase?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, optimization, data-transformation

I am trying to solve an optimization problem, that it's very similar to the knapsack problem but it can not be solved using the dynamic programming.
The problem I want to solve is very similar to this problem:

Given a set of products, i.e. $P = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}P_{c_{i}} $ where each $P_{c_i}$ is the set of products that belong to the category $c_i$. Also    we split each category $c_{i}$ as $\{\ G_{c_{i1}},...,G_{c_{ik}} \}\ $ where each group of products $G_{c_{ij}}$ contains products that  belong to the same group or sub-category. We want to pick one product from each group and give preference to products that the user is interested in.

Our goal is to create a user basket $Z$, $Z \subset  P$, which satisfies the following properties:

1. Personalization : The basket should contain products that are relevant to the user profile. We model our user profile as first $U_c$, a boolean vector $U_c= \{\ u_{c1},...,u_{cn} \}\ $, where $u_{c_{i}}$ is a boolean value that indicates whether the user $u$ is interested in a particular category $c_{i}$ or not. Second as $U_G= \{\ u_{g1},...,u_{gm} \}\ $. The final user basket $Z$, should maximize the coverage of categories and groups the user is interested in.
2. Budget: A basket should have a maximal budget. It captures the maximum amount of money a user is willing to pay. To this regards we set a threshold on the maximum budget of the basket $ \delta_{b} $. Which means that $\sum_{z \in Z} price(z) \leqslant \delta_{b}$.

We can than model this problem as an optimization problem:

\begin{align}
    &              
    & &    max(  \sum_{c \in C} x_{c}*u_c +  \sum_{c \in C} \sum_{g \in G_c}  u_g* x_{g} * u_c )  \\
%
    & \text{subject to} 
    & & \sum_{z \in Z} price(z) \leqslant \delta_{b} \\
%
    &&& 
  \end{align}

Where:

- $x_{c}$ is a boolean that captures whether category $c$ is covered in Z or not, it equals to 1 if the category is not covered and 0 otherwise.
- $x_g$ is a boolean that captures whether group $G$ is covered in Z or not, it equals to 1 if the group is not covered, and 0 otherwise.
- $u_g$ captures the user interest in the group of product G.
- $\delta_{b}$  is an adjustable parameter to control the maximum user budget.

The Figure below gives an example of the problem we want to solve.
[image]
 The categories are the principle nutrients for example:

- $c_1$=Carbs, $c_2$=Protein etc.
- The groups are for example for protein $G_{c_{21}}=Meat, G_{c_{22}}= Milk$.
- The user profile can be: $U_c= \{\ Carbs=1,Protein=1,Fat=0\}\ $, and $U_G= \{\ Meat=0.1, Milk=0.2, Pasta=0.1, Bread=07, Oil=0.01, Butter=0.6,\}\ $

For example:

- We suppose that $user_1$ has the following profile $U_c= \{\ Carbs=1,Protein=1,Fat=0\}\ $, and $U_G= \{\ Meat=0.8, Milk=0.2, Pasta=0.1, Bread=1, Oil=0.01, Butter=0.6,\}\ $ and his budget is 3 dollars. The best basket for him would be {Product11, Product21,Product41}.
- Whereas for $user_2$, having the following profile $U_c= \{\ Carbs=1,Protein=1,Fat=0\}\ $, and $U_G= \{\ Meat=0.8, Milk=0.2, Pasta=0.1, Bread=1, Oil=0.01, Butter=0.6,\}\ $ and his budget is 2 dollars. The best basket for him would be {Product11, Product41} because we won't choose a product from the second group of the protein category (i.e. Milk) because we want to maximize the sum of categories the user is interest in.

The dynamic programming can not be used for this problem because we change the sum of the values at every combination using the $x_c$ and $x_g$ variables. Until now I don't know under which mathematical problem this falls into. Any help or orientation would very much appreciable.

Here the DP solution of the original knapsack problem:
[image]
And here is how I suggest to modify it to solve my problem, I am not sure though that this is the right solution:
[image]

Thank you in advance.
Sincerely.

Comment: It is not clear to me why DP can't be used for this; your statement "The dynamic programming can not be used for this problem because we change the sum of the values at every combination using the xc and xg variables" seems to me to be saying "we can't use DP because when the values of our decision variables change, the value of the objective function changes", which is true of every optimization problem, including many that are routinely solved using DP.  As written, a binary integer programming routine will solve it too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, I really appreciate it. Actually I am still a beginner without a strong mathematical background. I have tried to modify the DP algorithm si that it solves my problem but I am not sure if it's the right solution or not. I have updated my question. Thank you in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: Actually I am not sure if it's a multiobjective-knapsack,  a multi-choice multiobjective-knapsack or a normal knapsack problem, I am a bit lost in all the available documentation.  @jbowman If you please have any reference to a paper or algorithm that is adapted to solve this problem please let me know. This will save me valuable time. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first step is to formulate it correctly; if you don't do that, everything afterwards is wasted time.  The way you have it written, it is just a knapsack problem.  I suspect that you may not have formulated it correctly; for example, can $x_g = 1$ if $x_c = 0$ for the same category?  It appears so, but it doesn't seem right to me (unfamiliar though I am with the details of the problem in question!)